# jquery smooth-div scroll doesn't work

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

for some reason the autoScollingMode is not working on my site: http://tinyurl.com/6ux32fe

that's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// Initialize the scroller
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
       mousewheelScrolling: true,
       manualContinuousScrolling: true,
       visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "false",
       autoScrollingMode: "always"
   });
}); // End query document ready
```

i can't find the error ...
thx for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked your site now it worked fine so I guess you solved the problem on your own?

If you want to you could also upgrade to Smooth Div Scroll version 1.3. You might have to alter some of the options to make the upgrade work though depending on which features you use.

Speaking of features - [Smooth Div Scroll 1.3](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) has support for touch which is nice since many people use iPhones, iPads etc.